# Filter object of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with a an object of objects and need a method to find all objects matching a certain value, ie in the example below I could pass the main object, 'city' and 'London' and be returned all events in London. Thank you

```
   {
      activityEvent_9: {
        eventId: 9,
        eventType: 'acitivty',
        city: 'London',
        eventStartTime: '2021-04-30T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-04-30T16:00:00',
      },
      trainingEvent_10: {
        eventId: 10,
        eventType: 'training',
        city: 'Manchester',
        eventStartTime: '2021-11-11T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-11-11T16:00:00',
      }
   }
```

Comment: Kindly post the code that you tried and is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to convert object to array of values and filter it with `filter()`.

```js
const data =  {
    activityEvent_9: {
        eventId: 9,
        eventType: 'acitivty',
        city: 'London',
        eventStartTime: '2021-04-30T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-04-30T16:00:00',
    },
    trainingEvent_10: {
        eventId: 10,
        eventType: 'training',
        city: 'Manchester',
        eventStartTime: '2021-11-11T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-11-11T16:00:00',
    }
}

const result = Object.values(data).filter(item=>item.city === "London") 
console.log(result);
```

You can also use `Object.keys()` to iterate over keys of object or `Object.entries()` to iterate both.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```
const data = {
  activityEvent_9: {
    eventId: 9,
    eventType: 'acitivty',
    city: 'London',
    eventStartTime: '2021-04-30T10:00:00',
    eventEndTime: '2021-04-30T16:00:00',
  },
  trainingEvent_10: {
    eventId: 10,
    eventType: 'training',
    city: 'Manchester',
    eventStartTime: '2021-11-11T10:00:00',
    eventEndTime: '2021-11-11T16:00:00',
  }
};
```

You can either use `Object.keys`, if you are targeting legacy browsers:

```
const events = (data, prop, value) => Object.keys(data).reduce(
  (list, key) => list.concat(data[key][prop] === value ? data[key] : []),
  []
);
```

Or you could use `Object.values`:

```
const events = (data, prop, value) => Object.values(data).filter(
  obj => obj[prop] === value
);
```

A call to `events(data, 'city', 'London')` will return an Array with all events in London.

Answer (score 0):

untested but should work

```js
const find = (object, key, value) => {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((acc, prop) => {
    if (object[prop][key] === value) {
      acc[prop] = object[prop];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
// usage
console.log(find(data, "name", "London"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar needs, solution I ended up using was,

```
data = < your object to be filtered >

Object.values(data).filter( record => record.city === 'London')

[
  {
    eventId: 9,
    eventType: 'acitivty',
    city: 'London',
    eventStartTime: '2021-04-30T10:00:00',
    eventEndTime: '2021-04-30T16:00:00'
  }
]
```

Object.values converts to list of object by values, assuming you do not need keys of the filtered object. we can then filter on key/value easily from there.

Answer (score -1):

Use things as follows:

- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter)
- your custom filter function
- [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const obj = {
      activityEvent_9: {
        eventId: 9,
        eventType: 'acitivty',
        city: 'London',
        eventStartTime: '2021-04-30T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-04-30T16:00:00',
      },
      trainingEvent_10: {
        eventId: 10,
        eventType: 'training',
        city: 'Manchester',
        eventStartTime: '2021-11-11T10:00:00',
        eventEndTime: '2021-11-11T16:00:00',
      }
   }

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => {
    return value.city === 'London';
  }))
);
```

Answer (score -3):

I used lodash.find

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find

It's under the Collections section, can pass arrays or objects

Comment: Using external library while native solution can be written in one line is probably not considered as best practice.