# How to iterate through object value

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

```
const schoolObj = {
  class10: { studentName: John, result: pass },
  class11: { studentName: Alis, result: pass },
  class12: { studentName: Nick, result: fail },
};
```

How to create list of studentName if result is pass. class10,11,12 all are dynamic values.I am stuck at how to access this dynamic value in iteration.

I want result like array of `student = [John, Alis]`

Comment: see: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: `Object.values(schoolObj).filter(e => e.result ==='pass')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Comment: or and [Filter object of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933394/filter-object-of-objects) and [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: @CBP changing the input values after answers have already been posted is discouraged and invalidates already accurate and upvoted answers.

Comment: Adjusting the existing answers to fit your ["new" structure](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76148066/5) isn't too hard either. For example `({ result }) => result === 'pass'` becomes `({ exam }) => exam.result === 'pass'`, a similar thing happens with the `studentName`.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the object values so that you only have the students that have passed left. Then map the student objects so that you get an array with their names.

```
const schoolArr = {
  class10: { studentName: 'John', result: 'pass' },
  class11: { studentName: 'Alis', result: 'pass' },
  class12: { studentName: 'Nick', result: 'fail' }
};

console.log(
  Object.values(schoolArr)
    .filter(({ result }) => result === 'pass')
    .map(({ studentName }) => studentName)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to your solution.

```
const schoolArr = {
  class10: { studentName: 'John', result: 'pass' },
  class11: { studentName: 'Alis', result: 'pass' },
  class12: { studentName: 'Nick', result: 'fail' }
};

const passStudents = Object.values(schoolArr).reduce((acc, { studentName, result }) => {
  if (result === 'pass') {
    acc.push(studentName);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(passStudents);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).